# how to assign a path from a function to an excel created with openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel

i'm new in Python, i have been trying to create a function "save_file()"; which provides me a path for saving an Excel file, Excel file is created from lists using openpyxl, for example:

```
import openpyxl as opxl
import tkinter as tk


wbk = opxl.Workbook()
worksheet1 = wbk.active
worksheet1.title = 'Species_concentration'
r = 2
for Hyd in Hyd_conc_list:
    worksheet1.cell(row = r, column = 1).value = Hyd
    r += 1
```

the thing is, once the Excel is created, i would like to assign the function "save_file()" to a button as a comman in an tkinter interface. I did this:

```
def save_file():
    ftype = [('Excel file', '*.xlsx')]
    idir = os.path.join (os.environ ['USERPROFILE'], 'Documents')
    path_name = tk.filedialog.asksaveasfilename (filetypes = ftype, initialdir = idir)
    wbk.save(path_name)    
 
button3 = tk.Button(wdw, text = 'SAVE', bg = 'gray14', bd = 4, fg = 'white', relief = 'raised', command = save_file)
```

but it's not working, i would appreciate any help, thanks a lot.

Comment: Whats the error? Whats wrong? Please explain

Comment: The problem is that the file isn't being saved,  the file browser is opened when i push the interface button  though (the button in the interface works but is saving no file), no message of error is prompted.

Comment: mmmmm im not sure, why check `print(path_name)` and verify, it is what you want

Comment: I'm sorry, it is my mistake, actually there is an error when i use the code it says: NameError: name 'wbk' is not defined.

Comment: Its hard to say from here, as it looks fine to me, anyway the error might mean that `wbk = opxl.Workbook()` is not getting executed? Is this inside a function or something then use`global wbk` or post the entire code

Comment: I have solved the problem, thank you!!!!!!!!! :D